# Change layout for specific category (productpage)

Tags: product, category, layout

I got a specific category and I want to change the layout for all the products the category contain.

If I want to change the layout(productpage) for all categories I need to edit the file `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml.`
But I just want to edit the layout for one category( the productpage layout)

I saw something with CategoryID but I don't really get it. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in admin panel itself.

Navigate to

> admin > catalog > manage category > select your category

Then go to custom design tab.

**Apply To Product => yes**

[Check this](http://john-dugan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/magento-cat-banner-category-layout-update.png)

And add below code in custom layout to change product view template.

```
<reference name="product.info">
   <action method="setTemplate"><template>your-template-file.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Ah I see - u missed the / in the second template bracket. It should be </template> Thank you and have a great day!