# Magento 1.9: Creating a page for just 1 product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, frontend, custom

I am trying to create a view for just 1 product, a gift card. 
We want some special front-end code to display some variable options for a gift card.

We have a gift card product type and it comes to some special options for selecting a price value. So the functionality of user-selected values is already coded.

I just want to take that product type and give it a spiffy front end without disrupting the other products.

We already have a product template, and it has some components that i need to remove. 
This is the path of our product view:

> app/design/frontend/vendor/vendor/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

There's also a:

> app/design/frontend/vendor/vendor/template/catalog/giftcard/price.phtml

(and other pages)

If someone could give me a high-level idea of steps I need to take, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: You have definetely have a handler for giftcard product type. Under that you can call you phtml file for that particular product type and then you can write your logic or codes to that phtml file.

Comment: We have the CE version. Gift cards are not native. Some dev added this in. 
I surly did see an xml and some controllers, but I cannot find where the product/view.pthtml was included as a template. Any other tips?

Comment: What do you mean by `I just want to take that product type and give it a spiffy front end without disrupting the other products. ` wich type of product ? `Simple`, `Configurable`... or you mean another thing ?

Comment: Gift card type product. I really don't know the history behind it, but i went to do this project, and the gift card type was already there, but it does not come with the CE version, but it has all user variable amount settings i need. I've only been coding with Magento for a month now, I might not be able to answer all your questions. But I'll do the best i can! 
I am trying this now too: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74757/change-layout-for-specific-category-productpage

Comment: I want to override the vendor/product/view.phtml
And make my own view.

Comment: that means only price section  remove or update right and all view content show like other product.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the product layout update for your spiffy html. Navigate to the product page in the admin > Catalog > Manage Products > search and click on the product. Then on the product page, click on *Design* on the left tabs. In the *Custom Layout Update*

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>vendor/catalog/product/spiffyView.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

In the the above example, the *phtml* file is located in

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/vendor/catalog/product/spiffyView.phtml

where *vendor* is a custom module name. To simplify testing, you can create a very simple 2-liner *phtml* file such as

```
<?php // super simple product template ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<h1><?php echo $_product->getSku() ?></h1>
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work for me. It would not change views.

Comment: I just did a test in my server and it worked for me. I edited my answer to add an example on the template path in the xml. To debug: disable your cache and turn on template path hint in admin. And if you still can't get it to work, then can you tell me your <action> xml and the complete path of your phtml file and if you have a custom module?

Comment: Awesome. I’ll try again! My below solution worked for me, I got to keep the prices, and I was able to get rid of the default vendor product template. I’m making a snuffy UI! However I want to explore your solution to in order to find multiple ways to solve this problem. I’m sure it will come up again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I added the below line to: app/design/frontend/vendor/vendor/layout/giftcard.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
             <!-- NEW CODE -->
             <template>giftcard/view.phtml</template>
             <!-- END NEW CODE -->
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

And removed:

```
<template>vendor_giftcard/catalog/price.phtml</template>
```

I copied page/view.phtml, removed the stuff I don't want, and created a new view.phtml template.

frontend/vendor/vendor/template/catalog/product/view.phtml is inherited by default and is not explicitly defined which was what was giving me trouble because I could not find the inclusion of it.

There is another view defined in the giftcard.xml called price.phtml and this handles the rendering of the form components for the giftcards.

Basically I need to add my new view, then add in the form components from the price.phtml view.

That's where I'm at. 
Understanding the basics of Magento's XML Templating system.